# How to create and add html elements dynamically with angular

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a shopping web app as a project for my master degree.

So my problem is that when I click the button to add a category(calling the function addCategory in my .ts file) I don't know how to create a div and add it to the html file with the id of the category's name, from the .ts file.

Any help it's welcomed.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <button (click)="addCategory()">Add category</button>
            <div id="Products">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h1>Shopping basket</h1>
            <div id="Shoppingbasket">
                <table id="Productstable" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Image</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                            <th scope="col">Units</th>
                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="Productstablebody">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Angular you **not** add elements to the .html. In Angular you has "variables" and create the html using these "variables" (in your case you need an array and the array can be an array of strings or an array of object) and `*ngFor`:https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#built-in-structural-directives. So you only need add elements to your array or change the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2) tutorial on the Angular web site to learn more.

You can create a list in your component, call it `categories`, then add more categories when you click the `addCategory` button. In your html template, you can loop through the categories and create an element for each of them.

I created a minimal example in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i4cjo9?file=src/app/input-overview-example.ts). Below is a rough example of how it can be done

#### Angular component

```js
categories: string[] = [];

addCategory() {
  this.categories.push('category');
}
```

#### HTML template

```html
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
  {{category}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make an array of category;
when you click add category add to the array then loop it in html like these

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories" [id]="category.name">
</div>
```